# For $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, is every point of $ \{ a\in \mathbb{R} : f \text{ is unbounded on every neighborhood of }a\} $ an isolated point?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

The function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is not assumed to have any other property and it's completely arbitrary. let  $A =\{ a\in \mathbb{R} : f \text{ is unbounded on every neighborhood of }a\} $. Can we say that every $ a \in A$ is an isolated point of $A$?

I can only say that if $f$ is continuous then $A = \varnothing$ because for every $ a \in \mathbb{R}$, $f$ is bounded on $[a-1, a+1]$ as this interval is compact. But for noncontinuous functions I don't have much intuition.

Comment: there are (even additive) functions that are unbounded on every neighborhood of any point

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1154432/42969

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can come up with some pretty pathological examples, such as
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
\lvert b \rvert, & x=\frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb{Q}\, 
  \text{ with } a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\, \text{ and } \gcd(a,b) = 1, \\
0, & x \notin \mathbb{Q}.
\end{cases}
$$
Due to the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and the denominators can be arbitrarily large, you can show that $f$ is unbounded in any neighborhood of any point in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: A variation on this theme: Let $D=\{d_n: n\in\Bbb N\}$ be a dense subset of $\Bbb R, $ with $m\ne n\implies d_m\ne d_n.$ Let $f(d_n)=n$. Regardless of what $f$ does on the rest of $\Bbb R,$  the function $f$ is unbounded on every non-empty open $U\subset\Bbb R$ because $U$ contains infinitely many members of $D.$

Comment: Oh that's nice.

Answer (score 3):

We can find functions such that $A$ is $\mathbb R$. For example let $f$ be the function defined as $f(x) = 0$ for irrational $x$ and $f(x)= q$ where $x=p/q$ for $p \in \mathbb Z$ and $q\in \mathbb Z^{+}$ with $p,q$ coprime.

Comment: Whoa. We came up with the same example at the same time. :-)

Comment: Beautiful ${}{}$